# Почему цикл не создает поля ввода Entry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, entry, init

```
class Example():

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.entry = Entry(width=30)
        self.entry.grid() #row=0, column=0 по умолчанию

        for r in range (3):
            for c in range (3):
                self.lbl = Entry()
                self.lbl.grid(row=r, column=c)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А где он выполняется, этот цикл?

Comment: Сам по себе код рабочий: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI3M2.png . Но если вы класс не создаете, то и текстовые поля не будут создаваться.

Comment: @insolor Класс он создаёт, а вот экземпляра класса не видать.

Comment: @СергейКох, да, я имел в виду создание экземпляра

Comment: А накой здесь `super().__init__()`? Что здесь "`super()`" и что он "`__init__()`"?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *


class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        
        self.entry = Entry(master, width=30)
        self.entry.grid()                      # row=0, column=0 по умолчанию

        for r in range(3):
            for c in range(3):
                lbl = Entry(master)
                lbl.grid(row=r, column=c+1)
                
root = Tk()
root.geometry('550x200')
root['bg'] = 'grey'

app = Example(root)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]